# Dynamic arrays using float

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got a small task I need to complete and I'm rather confused. This task has 3 parts to it which are:

1. Write a program that dynamically allocates a float array of a size specified by a user (currently working on - if anyone could check my code for this it would be appreciated.
2. It should then allow the user to input that number of floats, which should be stored in the array. (I have no clue what this means so if I'd appreciate someone explaining it if they could)
3. Program should print what was saved into the array, the sum, and the average value in the array, and exit.

As you could tell I'm new to C++ and coding in general so please spell it out for me wherever possible. It is mandatory that I am using pointers so I'm afraid I can't change that.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int length;

cout << “Please enter the length of the array: “;
cin >> length;

float * dArray = new float [length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
cin >> dArray[i] = i;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
cout << dArray[i] << “ “;
}
cout << ‘/n’;

int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
{
sum +=dArray[i];

avg =sum/length;

cout << “Sum is “ << sum << “/nAverage is “ << average;

delete [] dArray;
}
return 0;
}
```

Please explain the 2nd part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: And what is the problem you have with the program? Do you get build errors? For some specific input, what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: For (2), get each value from the input, just like you got the length. So the first loop should do `cin >> dArray[i]` to read each value.

Comment: remove those smart quotes or the compiler will consider it dumb quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding

> It should then allow the user to input that number of floats, which should be stored in the array. (I have no clue what this means so if I'd appreciate someone explaining it if they could)

It means that you have to let the user input the values to that array. What you are doing is giving them values yourself.

What you need to do is change

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        dArray[i] = i;
    }
```

to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        cin>>dArray[i];
    }
```

Also Note that `length` should be an int and not a float.

After completion, this would probably be the code you need ( although I would advice you to do the part of finding the sum and average by yourself and use this code I have posted as reference to check for any mistake, as finding the sum and average for this is really easy )

```
#include <iostream> // include library

using namespace std;

   int main() // main function
      {
        int length;           // changed length to int
        float sum = 0 , avg;  // variables to store sum and average
        cout << "Please enter the length of the array: "; // ask user for array
        cin >> length;

        float *dArray = new float[length];

        cout << "\nEnter " << length << " values to be added to the array\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
          {
            cin >> dArray[i];  //accepting values
            sum += dArray[i];   // finding sum
          }

        avg = sum / length;  //the average

        cout << "\nThe array now contains\n";    // Displaying the array
        for (   int i = 0;  i < length; i++)     // with the loop
          {
            cout << dArray[i] << " ";
          }

        cout << "\nThe sum of all values in the array is " << sum;  // the sum
        cout << "\n\nThe average value is " << avg;                 // the average

        delete[] dArray;
        return 0;
      }
```

---

## EDIT

After getting your comment, I decided to post this new code. ( I am assuming what you meant is that the program should repeat as long as the user wants )
I have done it by using a do while loop.

```
#include <iostream> // include library

using namespace std;

   int main() // main function
      {
        int length;           // changed length to int
        char a;               // a variable to store the user choice 
        do
          {
            float sum = 0 , avg;  // variables to store sum and average        
            cout << "\nPlease enter the length of the array: "; // ask user for array
            cin >> length;

            float *dArray = new float[length];

            cout << "\nEnter " << length << " values to be added to the array\n";
            for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
              {
                cin >> dArray[i];  //accepting values
                sum += dArray[i];   // finding sum
              }

            avg = sum / length;  //the average

            cout << "\nThe array now contains\n";    // Displaying the array
            for (   int i = 0;  i < length; i++ )    // with the loop
              {
                cout << dArray[i] << " ";
              }

            cout << "\nThe sum of all values in the array is " << sum;  // the sum
            cout << "\n\nThe average value is " << avg;                 // the average
            
            cout << "\n\nDo you want to try again ( y/n ) ?\n";
            cin >> a;
          
            delete[] dArray;
          }while( a =='Y' || a == 'y'  );  // The do while loop repeats as long as the character entered is Y or y
        
        return 0;
      }
```

Well, hope this is what you were looking for, if not, please do notify me with a comment...       :)

---

Just so you know, the new code you have posted doesn't even compile. Here are some of the problems.

```
cin >> dArray[i] = i;
```

You don't need to use  `= i` here. Just `cin >> dArray[i] ;` is enough.

The next problem is

```
cout << ‘/n’;
```

First of all, its `\n` and not `/n`. You also need to enclose it in double quotes and not single quotes. That is `cout << "\n";`

Next one, you have not defined the variable `avg` . Also note that you have also used an undefined variable `average`, which I assume you meant `avg`.

Now here's one of the main problems , You have not closed the curly brackets you opened. You open the brackets for for loops, but forget to close it. I'm leaving that part to you as you need to learn that part yourself by trying.

Now Here's one problem I don't understand, you have used `“ “`, which is somehow not the same as `" "`. I don't know if it's something wrong with my computer, or if it's a totally different symbol. My compiler couldn't recognize it. If its not causing any trouble on your end, then don't mind it.

Well, this sums up the problems I noticed in your code ( the problems that I noticed ).

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. How could I change this to be able to enable the user to repeat the selection or exit? I'm not sure of the syntax necessary

Comment: @DouglasTyler , "repeat the selection or exit?", what do you mean by that ? If you mean to ask the user if they want to repeat the whole process again, then I will add a new code for it.

Comment: they are called smart quotes which are replaced automatically when typing "stupid" quotes in a text editor like MS Word

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc , thanks a lot for notifying. I was actually pretty confused at what they were. DO they work on our compilers ? Mine didn't recognize them.

Comment: No, they're invalid characters in C and C++

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc , so we must change them to `"` on our compiler , right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are too simple for us to just give you the answers, but I've commented your code with suggestions on how to solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  float length; //it doesn't make sense for something to be of a float length
                //should be size_t instead
  cout << "Please enter the length of the array: ";
  cin >> length;

  float *dArray = new float[length];

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    dArray[i] = i; //this line is incorrect
    //how should we read the data into this array?
    //we've used cin before
  }

  for (int i = 0;  i < length; i++)
  {
    cout << dArray[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << '\n';
  //now we've output the array, just need to output the sum and average value
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
  {
     sum += //what should go here?
  }
  int average = //how should we calculate the average?

  cout << "Sum is " << sum << "\nAverage is " << average;

  delete[] dArray;
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I've edited the code with my attempted improvements. Please let me know if I've missed anything or I've made it worse...